# Assigning Partners (From CCC competition)

Tags: java

The CEMC is organizing a workshop with an activity involving pairs of students. They decided to assign
partners ahead of time. You need to determine if they did this consistently. That is, whenever A is a partner
of B, then B is also a partner of A, and no one is a partner of themselves.
Input
The input consists of three lines. The first line consists of an integer N (1 < N ≤ 30), which is the number of
students in the class. The second line contains the first names of the N students separated by single
spaces. (Names contain only uppercase or lowercase letters, and no two students have the same first
name). The third line contains the same N names in some order, separated by single spaces.
The positions of the names in the last two lines indicate the assignment of partners: the i-th name on the
second line is the assigned partner of the i-th name on the third line.
Output
The output will be good if the two lists of names are arranged consistently, and bad if the arrangement of
partners is not consistent.
Sample Input 1
4
Ada Alan Grace John
John Grace Alan Ada
Sample Output 1
good
Explanation for Sample 1
Ada and John are partners, and Alan and Grace are partners. This arrangement is consistent.
Sample Input 2
7
Rich Graeme Michelle Sandy Vlado Ron Jacob
Ron Vlado Sandy Michelle Rich Graeme Jacob
Sample Output 2
bad
Explanation for Sample 1
Graeme is partnered with Vlado, but Vlado is partnered with Rich. This is not consistent. It is also
inconsistent because Jacob is partnered with himself.

Here is my work, I wonder why it doesn't work???

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CCCHW4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = reader.nextInt();  //how many names
        String [][] combo = new String [2][n];
        double value = 0;

        combo [0] [0] = reader.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //input the names
            combo [0] [i] = reader.nextLine();
        }
        combo [1] [0] = reader.nextLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {  //input the names
            combo [1] [j] = reader.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n++; ++i) {
            if ((combo [0][i]).equals(combo [1][i])) {  //check if partner with himself/herself
                System.out.println(" same " + combo [0][i] + combo [1][i]);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {  //each combo
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {  // each column
                int determineValue = 0; //determine if any guy partnered with more than one person
                if ((combo [0] [i]+combo [1] [i]).equals(combo [0] [j]+combo [1] [j]) ||            //check, if partner with two person
                        (combo [0] [i]+combo [1] [i]).equals(combo [1] [j]+combo [0] [j])) {
                    determineValue += 1;
                }
                if (determineValue != 2) { //same combo one time, reversed combo one time, so two.
                    value += 1;
                    System.out.println("yes2");
                }
            }
        }

        if (value == 0) {
            System.out.print("good");
        } else {
            System.out.print("bad");}
    }
}
```

Comment: combo [0] [0] = reader.nextLine();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //input the names
   combo [0] [i] = reader.nextLine();
  }
  combo [1] [0] = reader.nextLine();
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {  //input the names
   combo [1] [j] = reader.nextLine();
  }          ----These two for loops doesnt work because they dont allow me to input  combo [0] [0] and combo [1] [0], why they just skipped these two?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a good question, that is likely to receive an answer.

Comment: As it stands, you question is lacking in the following: 1. The question is badly formatted. re-read it, and format accordingly (the "How To Ask" link above will show you how). 2. You did not say what your code did differently than expected. 3. Some of the relevant information is in a comment - edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution to your homework exercise.

I first ran a few tests by hand and realized that the program output can never be GOOD if there are an odd number of students, so I added a condition that the entered number of students must be an even number.

My algorithm is to use two, separate, one dimensional arrays rather a single, two dimensional array. I loop through the second array (`partners` in the below code) and for each "partner", I search the first array (`students` in the code below) for that "partner". If I find the "partner" in the `students` array then I check whether the pairs are the same. As soon as I fail to find a matching pair, I exit the loop and the program prints BAD.

Note that I only need to search half of the `partners` array since if I find matches for all the students in the first half of the array, then the second half must all have matches also.

Also note that I added a lot of checks for valid input, including ensuring that the entered number of students is a positive integer, i.e. not a number with a decimal point or a minus sign. I also check that the correct number of names are entered and that each list of names contains only unique names, i.e. the same name cannot appear more than once in a list. The user is asked to re-enter invalid data, repeatedly, until [s]he enters valid data, i.e. a correct number of students and correct lists of names.

Lastly note that I check the validity of the parameters in methods `getNames()` and `getNumberOfStudents()`. I feel it is important since I always remind myself that the [Ariane 5 rocket failed](https://www.bugsnag.com/blog/bug-day-ariane-5-disaster) because the software did not check the validity of method parameters.

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Pairings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfStudents = getNumberOfStudents(stdin);
        String[] students = getNames(stdin, numberOfStudents);
        String[] partners = getNames(stdin, numberOfStudents);
        int limit = numberOfStudents / 2;
        boolean bad = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfStudents; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    if (students[j].equals(partners[i])) {
                        if (partners[j].equals(students[i])) {
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                bad = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (bad) {
            System.out.println("BAD");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("GOOD");
        }
    }

    private static String[] getNames(Scanner stdin, int number) {
        if (number <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not positive: " + number);
        }
        Objects.requireNonNull(stdin, "Null scanner.");
        String[] names = new String[0];
        int count = 0;
        do {
            System.out.printf("Enter %d unique names (separated by single space)%n", number);
            String str = stdin.nextLine();
            names = str.split("\\s+");
            count = names.length;
            if (count != number) {
                System.out.printf("You entered %d names and not %d%n", count, number);
            }
            else {
                Set<String> nameSet = new HashSet<String>(number);
                for (String name : names) {
                    if (nameSet.contains(name)) {
                        System.out.printf("%s appears more than once%n", name);
                        count = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        nameSet.add(name);
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (count != number);
        return names;
    }

    private static int getNumberOfStudents(Scanner stdin) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(stdin, "Null scanner.");
        String str;
        int numberOfStudents;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter number of students (even number between 2 & 30): ");
            str = stdin.nextLine();
            try {
                numberOfStudents = Integer.parseInt(str);
                if (numberOfStudents < 0) {
                    System.out.printf("%d is a negative number%n", numberOfStudents);
                }
                else if (numberOfStudents % 2 == 1) {
                    System.out.printf("%d is not an event number%n", numberOfStudents);
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException xNumFmt) {
                System.out.printf("%s is not a whole number%n", str);
                numberOfStudents = 1;
            }
        } while (numberOfStudents % 2 == 1);
        return numberOfStudents;
    }
}
```